# $.post("file.php",{},null, "json").done(function(data){} doesen't work (Does not load the dada from php)

Tags: php, jquery, json, post

I amb trying to let work a $.post jquery function using JSON data, but the case is that when I expect to return the data, looks like the method is never called, or never triggered. I don't understand why in this case is not working, when I just made a copy/paste from the same code in the same .php file. Here I let you the code:

```
 $.post("operacions/obtenirIdUs.php", {idUsConcret : idUsConcret}, null, "json").done(function(data){
      alert("hello there");
     $("#NomUsuariLinea").val(data.Nom);
     $("#LlinatgesUsuariLinea").val(data.Llinatges);
     $("#ContrassenyaUsuariLinea").val(data.contrassenya);
     $("#EmailUsuariLinea").val(data.email);


    })
```

The alert is never shown. I would really apreciate any solution, due the case that this code is working with other examples in the same page as I said before.

Here I let you my php.file: "obtenirIdUs.php"

```
<?php
include("../connexio.php");
$idUsConcret= $_POST['idUsConcret'];

$arrayDatos = array();


$EditarFactura = "SELECT * FROM usuari WHERE idUsuari = '".$idUsConcret."'";
echo $EditarFactura;
$connexio = mysqli_query($conn,$EditarFactura) or die(mysqli_error());

while($llistaFactura = mysqli_fetch_array($connexio)){
$arrayDatos['Nom'] = $llistaFactura['Nom'];
$arrayDatos['Llinatges'] = $llistaFactura['Llinatges'];
$arrayDatos['contrassenya'] = $llistaFactura['contrassenya'];
$arrayDatos['email'] = $llistaFactura['email'];
$arrayDatos['rol'] = $llistaFactura['rol'];


}
echo json_encode($arrayDatos);
?>
```

Once again, thank you.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Hi, no. Everything looks fine, but the .val is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace "done" by "success":

```
$.post("operacions/obtenirIdUs.php", {idUsConcret : idUsConcret}, null, "json").success(function(data){...});
```

Comment: Nope, it still getting the same issue :/

Comment: Do you have any information from console? (In chrome, for example, press f12 and in "network" tab chose your post request)

Comment: The console doesen't give me any information pressing f12 :/

Comment: The print Err is giving me: [object Object]

Comment: Can you "expand" your [object Object] to show his content?

Comment: I've already solve it, i Had a echo in the php file. Thank you a lot man.

Comment: No problems. Be careful next time )

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$.post("operacions/obtenirIdUs.php", {idUsConcret : idUsConcret}, null, "json").then(
 function(data){
   //handle your data
},function(err){
   //handle error
});
```

Comment: Hello, yes, now at least the function redirect me to the "handle error". Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: The print Err is giving me: [object Object]

Comment: open the network monitor and see what the response is and the status of the request

Comment: Hi, I've solve it, the problem was I had a F**cking echo in the php file when I made some testing.

Answer (score -1):

I've already solved the mistake, I had a echo "hello"; on the php file, and cause of that the json encode was not working.

Thank you all of you who tried to help me.

Have a good day!